# Angular / how to get the api return data

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe, observable

I use pipe and map to send to return value.

```
add(content): Observable<Comment> {
    return this.apiService
               .post('/api/comment/', comment)
               .pipe(map(data => data.comment));
}
```

I want to check the 'data' value.

For example, using `console.log`

```
add(content): Observable<Comment> {
     return this.apiService
                .post('/api/comment/', comment)
                .pipe(map(data => data.comment, data => console.log('data.comment :', data.comment)));
}
```

In this case, it does not work.

I wonder how to use it in this case.

Comment: Have you suscribed to it?

Comment: Yes. subscribed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `tap` operator combined with `map`

```
add(content): Observable<Comment> {
     return this.apiService.post('/api/comment/', comment)
                           .pipe(tap(data => console.log('data.comment :', data.comment)),
                                 map(data => data.comment));
}
```

`tap` is used when you don't need to change the response shape, you need something to log or to add into the local storage and so on.